# Rescaling raster to match another precision of coordinates using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, coordinates, arcgis-10.5

I am working with 2 DEMs using ArcMap 10.5. Both have a resolution of 0.5 m but the first one has coordinates such as X=243600.5 m and the second one X=243600.3m.
I need to make sure they both have coordinates like the first one (243600.5m). I only have the file as a .tif, I do not have the original set of points or the TIN.
I have tried to clip the second raster to files with the right form of coordinates (using the various options), to export the second raster, to resample it, to force things with the environment settings.
I end up either with the right result but with a shift in the cells values (which I don't want) or it does not give me the right form of coordinates.

Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: Check out the "snap raster" environment setting: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/snap-raster.htm

Comment: Have you tried the [Shift Tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/shift.htm)?